# Get height and width from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to get the height and width from the end of a url BEFORE LOADING THE IMG. The url I have looks like this:

`https://images.or/domain/hiddenuid_2021_logo.webp?auto=compress,format&rect=0,0,350,400&w=350&h=400`

As you can see both width and height are represented by w=350 and h=400

I am using React/Nextjs.

Once I can get the height and width, I will then display it in the  container as follows:

```
<Image src={image.url} width={width} height={height} />
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

I found a answer with almost same question:

```js
var url_string = "https://images.or/domain/hiddenuid_2021_logo.webp?auto=compress,format&rect=0,0,350,400&w=350&h=400"; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
var width = url.searchParams.get("w");
var height = url.searchParams.get("h");

alert("Width is: " + width)

alert("Height is: " + height)
```

Comment: I dont have a option to vote. I thought that it might help the OP

Comment: It isn't a big deal if the user has provided an answer for the question. The question has been asked, the solution is given

Comment: Then you should flag it as a duplicate so others who do have the rep can close it as a dupe

Comment: @AsianCat You can still flag things as duplicate (minimum rep: 15). The reviewers will handle the closing / deleting.

Comment: Okay I have flagged ;)

Comment: @0xsapphir3 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled#:~:text=target%20(see%20below).-,Should%20I%20answer%20it%3F,-Generally%2C%20no%2C%20not

Comment: Oh i see the highlighted part. I understood.